# Cannot set headers after they are sent to clients in node.js

Tags: node.js

My code is not working . I am beginner and don't know my problem. Kindly help.I have seen one or two solution on stackoverflow but didnot get .
This is code.

```
app.post('/post',(request,response)=>{
    var description=request.body.description;
    var contact_number=request.body.contact_number;
    var city=request.body.city;
    var budget=request.body.budget;
    var category=request.body.optradio;                    
   var query=connection.query("insert into jobs(Jobs_id,Description,Category,City,Contact_number,Budget) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)",[null,description,category,city,contact_number,budget],function(err){
        if(err)
            console.log(err);
        else
        response.send("successful");
        
        }); 
   response.redirect('/data');
    });
   
app.get('/data',function(request,response){
 connection.query("SELECT * FROM jobs ORDER BY Jobs_id DESC",(err, rows,fields) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);        
        }
        else { 
            response.render('feed', {title : 'Jobs Details',
        items: rows }) 
        }
    });
});
app.listen(3000);
```

This is the error
[image]

Comment: You don't you use promise to get result inside then block of first query ?

Comment: as i mentioned i am beginner and i don't know how to resolve this issue :)

Comment: Do you want to create two endpoints or inside one endpoint. You should get all result ?

Comment: @xMayank actually i have created two separate files one in which user submits the form it store in database and other when we click button all data is shown on webpage from database. files were working good separately but i want to place both in one .js file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pp.post('/post', (request, response) => {
  var description = request.body.description;
  var contact_number = request.body.contact_number;
  var city = request.body.city;
  var budget = request.body.budget;
  var category = request.body.optradio;
  var query = connection.query("insert into jobs(Jobs_id,Description,Category,City,Contact_number,Budget) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)", [null, description, category, city, contact_number, budget],
    function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        response.redirect('/data');
      }
    });
  });
 
  app.get('/data', function (request, response) {
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM jobs ORDER BY Jobs_id DESC", (err, rows, fields) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      else {
        response.render('feed', {
          title: 'Jobs Details',
          items: rows
        })
      }
    });
  });
  app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: i have seen this answer on another post but i didn't get it

Comment: you are not using the if and else properly as i can see in this code

Comment: check now and let  me know

Comment: yup it did. Thanks a lot

Comment: but what was the mistake

Comment: second response was outside the loop. so it was sent after the if else executed so that was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

There can be only one response to single HTTP request. In your code, you are first trying to send response with

```
response.send("successful");
```

but this on its own doesn't break the flow of the function which means that if the condition is actually met then this will execute and the execution continues and finds another response, in this case

```
response.redirect('/data');
```

and it will try to send another response to the original http request but at this point it is already too late because one response has already been send.

To solve this issue in general, you can place `return` in front of any line of code that is closing the the connection (response.send, response.redirect, ...). That way, the function's execution is terminated at the first response, whichever it is.

So you could do something like

```
var query=connection.query("insert into jobs(Jobs_id,Description,Category,City,Contact_number,Budget) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)",[null,description,category,city,contact_number,budget],function(err){
    if(err)
        console.log(err);
    else
        return response.send("successful");
    }); 
    
    return response.redirect('/data');
});
```

Comment: Oh oaky. I got it . Thanks  a lot